# Show/hide input text based on select value width ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a problem with AngularJS and I haven't found the tools to help me. I have a select box to select a status.

I need to update my "ng-model" when I submit the form, so the ng-model-options is good here.

My problem is that I need to show an input text if my option is "status_2":

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="product in products">

   <form>

    <select ng-model="product.myStatus" class="form-control" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}" required>
      <option value="status_1">{{'status_1' | translate}}</option>
      <option value="status_2">{{'status_2' | translate}}</option>
    </select>

    <div ng-show="product.myStatus == 'status_2'">
      <input type="text" ng-model="product.comment" class="form-control" ng-required="product.myStatus == 'status_2'">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" />

   </form>

  </li>
</ul>
```

But it doesn't work. The input text doesn't appear. I know why, but I don't know how to do this and if I can do it another way.

My version of AngularJS is 1.5.5.

Comment: You know why the input doesn't show up, so you should know why it's not working... What's the question? I mean, it seems obvious that if you want the model to update after they've selected something, you need to change your `ng-model-options`.

Comment: Yeah, but i don't know how to do that another way :/

Answer (score 0):

the ng-model-options means the model is only updating when you hit submit.  I dont think you want this.

-------------------------Original comment-------------

Im not sure what the ng-model-options is, but when i removed it, the show/hide updates fine:

```
                <select ng-model="product.myStatus" class="form-control" xxxng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}" required>
                  <option value="status_1">{{'status_1'}}</option>
                  <option value="status_2">{{'status_2'}}</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: ng-model-options is for : "not validate if you dont' submit".  I dont' want that my product.myStatus take the value if you don't validate the form.

Comment: ok. You may have to use a separate object to hold the model values, and copy them over to the main object after the validation/submission takes place.

Comment: oh ! That's a good idea ! do you have an exemple ? If not, i will search something like that ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The model is updated on 'submit'. I think u can try `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"` The model value will get changed 'on-blur'.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this. Use a copy of the products for the loop. then, when validated and submitted, update the products to the new values:

HTML:

```
        <li ng-repeat="product in temp">
```

JS:

```
        $scope.products = [{myStatus: "status_1"},{myStatus: "status_2"}];
        $scope.temp = angular.copy($scope.products);


        $scope.submit = function(){
            $scope.products = angular.copy($scope.temp);

        }
```